# Codepen Returning Empty Array When Expecting Few Items

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, variables, codepen

I'm trying to console log a variable that should contain an array. However, in Codepen, it returns an empty array. I'm expecting it to return contents of the list item.

Here's the [Codepen](https://codepen.io/ericnguyen23/pen/EBrodo?editors=1111) along w/ some snippet code:

This is a React project, btw, which is why I'm using className instead of class.

HTML

```
      <ul className="nav">
        <li>
          <a>Products</a>

          <div className="subnav-block">
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a>Product A</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a>Product B</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
      <li>
      <a>About</a>

      <div className="subnav-block">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a>About Us</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a>Press</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
      </ul>
```

JS

```
const nav = document.querySelectorAll('.nav > li');

console.log(nav)
```

Codepen is returning:

```
[Object NodeList] {Length: 0}
```

Comment: JavaScript can't find your nodes because you used `className` attribute instead of `class`

Answer (score 1):

Because `className` isn't how you add a HTML class - it's simply `class`.

```js
const nav = document.querySelectorAll(".nav > li");

console.log(nav);
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
  <li>
    <a>Products</a>

    <div class="subnav-block">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a>Product A</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a>Product B</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a>About</a>

    <div class="subnav-block">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a>About Us</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a>Press</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

To keep using `className`, use an attribute selector:

```js
const nav = document.querySelectorAll("[className='nav'] > li");

console.log(nav);
```

```html
<ul className="nav">
  <li>
    <a>Products</a>

    <div className="subnav-block">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a>Product A</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a>Product B</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a>About</a>

    <div className="subnav-block">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a>About Us</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a>Press</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I should added it's a React project. In codepen I do have Babel as JS processor so thought using className is correct. However, I've still did try your solution but did not work.

Answer (score 1):

If this is in a react app make sure you are calling the code in the correct place so that the dom has actually been updated with your markup before the query is being called. If you are using a class component move your code inside `componentDidMount`

```
componentDidMount() {
  const nav = document.querySelectorAll(".nav > li");
  console.log(nav);
}
```

If you are using hooks place it inside `useEffect`

```
useEffect(() => {
  const nav = document.querySelectorAll('.nav > li')
  console.log(nav)
}, [])
```

here is a working example using hooks: https://codesandbox.io/s/currying-monad-t6104?fontsize=14